# React: Make child route's address active when visiting parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have nested routes that look like the following:

```
<Route path='parent' component={Parent}>
    <Route path='child1' component={Child1}/>
    <Route path='child2' component={Child2}/>
    <Route path='child3' component={Child3}/>
</Route>
```

I'm trying to make it when you visit `/parent`, you're redirected to `/parent/child1`. I've tried using `IndexRoute` from React-Router on the `Child1` component, but that merely makes `Child1` the component when you visit `/parent`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IndexRedirect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#indexredirect) component for this.

```
<Route path='parent' component={Parent}>
    <IndexRedirect to="/child1" />
    <Route path='child1' component={Child1}/>
    <Route path='child2' component={Child2}/>
    <Route path='child3' component={Child3}/>
</Route>
```